# Return SQS response as json

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is there a way to get the response of SQS Api as Json?

I need to do it because from the browser I need to get the information of the queue, but as it is cross-domain it needs to be in json(p)

@see [Receive XML response from Cross-Domain Ajax request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552375/receive-xml-response-from-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery-nor-yql-either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS does not provide a JSON interface.  You could implement a proxy on your web server which returns the information in whatever format you want.  That would also remove the cross-domain issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this. I can not have a proxy-alike in my server cause I don't want handle those connections.