# Call a remote XML by Ajax call

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml in a remote server. Now i want to call it with ajax. IE is giving the required result. But Firefox and chrome cant. Please give me the solution. I google it but did not find the solution.

```
$.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", 
    dataType: "xml", 
    success: function(node) 
    { 
    alert(node); 
    }, 
    error: function() 
    { 

    alert("Network Error"); 

    } 
    });
```

Comment: try changing the URL to "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml" and see if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You are definitely stuck with ajax cross-domain issue.there is two approaches that you can use now.

- First is using a proxy.example [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).
- Using [cross-origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/)

AS this is a little wast topic to share here.I won't go to implement it here on your code.But If you check these things I am sure you can sort this issue out.

Edit a simple google search ended up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552375/receive-xml-response-from-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery) .
Where some one else had explained the solution more clearly.You can take use of it.

Comment: Dear AKS, Thank you so much for your reply. You will please guide me how to do it. I also put $.support.cors = true; in my code but fail. Please help me. i need this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Its realy hard to use ajax cross-domain, check out googles.
Use ajax to call .php in ur serwer and use curl post.

Im bad english so

Create call GET to ajax.php
and in ajax.php write.

```
echo GETrequest("http://www.w3schools.com/");
```

here is my 2 curl function, just change end lines, $this->data to return

```
private function GETrequest($link){
        $zapytanie = curl_init(); // adres strony
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4"); // useragent
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3", "Connection: keep-alive","Cache-Control: max-age=0","text/html; charset=UTF-8"));
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies/'.$this->adres_ip.'/cookies.txt'); // ciacha
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies/'.$this->adres_ip.'/cookies.txt'); // ciacha
        $this->data = curl_exec($zapytanie);
        $this->getinfo = curl_getinfo($zapytanie);
        curl_close($zapytanie);
    }
    private function POSTrequest($link,$post){
        $zapytanie = curl_init(); // adres strony
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4"); // useragent
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3","Referer: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit", "Connection: keep-alive","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies/'.$this->adres_ip.'/cookies.txt'); // ciacha
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies/'.$this->adres_ip.'/cookies.txt'); // ciacha
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($zapytanie, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $this->data = curl_exec($zapytanie);
        $this->getinfo = curl_getinfo($zapytanie);
        curl_close($zapytanie);
    }
```

Comment: Dear Michał Szałapski. Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately i cant use php. I have to do this with jquery only. Please provide me the solution. yes you are right I stuck in cross domain.

Comment: I think, its impossible, u need to use a php, because w3school will need to add u domain manualy to accept ur GET and POST's

Comment: aswell u can try $.get or $.post but i think, will not work too. IE works because its to oooold and bad. New browser will not send this request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with pure jquery. You will need to do one of the following:

1. Use a proxy server (somewhere where you can run the request through a proxy, saying using PHP).
2. If you own `w3schools.com`, you can enable your own site to access the XML via JSON (via enabling CORS).

Comment: Thank you Chris. Will you please guide me. I can't use PHP. Please help me how to do it via json. I already put $.support.cors = true; in my code.

Comment: As per my answer. There is literally no way (at present) to achieve this without one of the above two options. Do you have a server somewhere you can use? Or do you own w3schools.com?

Comment: No not at all. Actually we have a server where our project will be uploded. Please help me if you can..

Comment: So you have access to PHP?

Comment: Well I think you should start a new question regarding how to pull data from a server using a server (you'll need to figure out what language is installed on your server, be it PHP, ASP, etc)

Comment: I do understand the downvote, I was being a bit sarcastic with point 2 - but in reality (and for any future people visiting this page) if he did own the remote site (be it w3schools.com or another) enabling CORS would do the trick for cross domain