# Ajax xml request failing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a remote xml file so I can parse it and return some results, but this Ajax GET request keeps failing.  See it on a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/efxLvmey/3/).  Note: this also fails if you use `dataType: 'xml'`

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ultrasoundoftheweek.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml",
        dataType: 'text',
        cache:'false',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("yes");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert("no");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the ajax url is cross domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a remote XML by Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504347/call-a-remote-xml-by-ajax-call)