# ASP.NET, JQuery AJAX XML parse error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, xml

I am trying to get my phone number by getting xml info from xml website. The xml website was able to detect my userID computer and gave me a list of my profile included my phone number.

Here is example of xml displayed,

```
<MyData>
 <user>
   <uid>U580784</uid>  
   <sn>Bell</sn> 
   <givenName>James</givenName> 
   <initials>B</initials>  
   <Company>Happy Company</Company> 
   <Department>IT</Department>  
   <co>UNITED STATES</co>  
   <telephoneNumber>888-888-8888</telephoneNumber> 
 </user>
</MyData>
```

I want JQuery AJAX to get telephone number from `<telephoneNumber>` and display on alert box.

However I keep getting Ajax error thrown from error alert. Do I miss something?

you will see a xml link in AJAX below that have unique search `UserID=me` mean only detect when access to website or I can replace to `UserID=U555555` to get other person phone number.

Here is my Jquery and asp codes,

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://servername.company.happy.com/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=me",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('user').each(function () {
                        var phone = $(this).find("telephoneNumber").text();
                        alert(phone);
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error!'+ textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });


    });

</script>

 <h3>Test Test Header</h3>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <h3>Test Test Main</h3>
    </br>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

    </br>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hey there, which error are you getting up?

Comment: just a pop up error from AJAX error function that said "ERROR! error - No Transport"

Comment: dataType:xml doesn't do anything in this context. I suggest you to add contentType to xml contentType: "text/xml",

Comment: @PranavRam I removed datatype and still get errorthrown

Comment: @Maximiliano I did tried contentType. Still same error result.

Comment: It's because it is a cross domain request. Cross domain requests are restricted to jsonp dataType. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552375/receive-xml-response-from-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: It's true cross-domain doesn't work but I don't see how you jump to that conclusion :) There´s not a reference to any domain except the ajax request

Comment: @MaximilianoRios In my opinion the first two sentences of the question point out that the xml is obtained from a website that the developer does not control. That's why I mentioned the cross domain in my comment.

Comment: I think your guess is really good, and in that case you have an answer. Randomly yesterday I switched two websites in my computer and changed the port to test something and every ajax stopped working due to this problem. I'm implementing a cross-domain solution now

Comment: I want to clarify it. That xml website and the asp.net website I use are both in same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple answer and it really strange.
I just need to add `$.support.cors = true;` above Ajax call to enables cross origin resource sharing.
It like subdomain.happy.com is not equal to subdomain2.happy.com

Comment: and I also added `contentType: "text/xml"`. I just vote + your suggested